# Configuration Error when trying to connect mongodb database in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I keep getting
`pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'`
even though I have all the latest versions of pymongo and dnspython installed.
This is my code...

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Nethrenial:notrealpassword@db-for-toodooo.shhiq.mongodb.net/TooDooo?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
users = client.users.find()
user_list = []
for user in users:
    user_list.append(user)
print(user_list)
```

And this is the complete exception,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 72, in _resolve_uri
    results = resolver.query('_mongodb._tcp.' + self.__fqdn, 'SRV',
TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\TooDooo\database_functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Nethrenial:nethrenial@db-for-toodooo.shhiq.mongodb.net/TooDooo?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 639, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 500, in parse_uri
    nodes = dns_resolver.get_hosts()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 102, in get_hosts
    _, nodes = self._get_srv_response_and_hosts(True)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 83, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts
    results = self._resolve_uri(encapsulate_errors)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 79, in _resolve_uri
    raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lifetime'
```

Comment: Please post your output of `pip freeze`

Answer (score 6):

If you use Python 3, you must use `dnspython3` instead of `dnspython`. This lib actually uses `dnspython` under the hood, but installs an incorrect version, 1.15.0, the same as for main library. You must change it manually to 2.1.0. On PC (Windows) it also installs `starlette` lib. Never change it's version to upgrade, it stops working.

Incompatibility issues and poor ecosystem support seems to be a common problem in the Python world.

Comment: I need to try this and yeah lot of incompatibility issues. I tried node.js for a while now. I think it's a good fit for me. Anyway, thank you for answering my question, appreciate it a lot.

Comment: pip install dnspython==2.1.0 worked for me; I also ignored conflict error.

Answer (score 2):

In Most cases, this occurs because of outdated dnspython lib.
I solved my issue just by re-installing / updating dnspython

```
pip3 install dnspython
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing `pip install dnspython` didn't work for me. The following code did the job:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import dns.resolver

dns.resolver.default_resolver=dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers=['8.8.8.8']
```

Answer (score 0):

For me uninstall/install pymongo solved the issue (updating did not help):

```
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo
```